# REACT, setInterval keeps returning NAN even though state is a number

Tags: reactjs, state, setinterval

I'm pretty new to react and I'm trying to create a countdown timer, however, when I call the setInterval function onClick, my state changes to NAN and does not decrement, even though the initial state is a number

```
  interval = () => {
    this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(({seconds}) => ({
        second: parseInt(seconds) - 1
      }))
    }, 1000)
  }
```

```
          <button onClick={this.interval} className="start">START</button>
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `second`?

Comment: And `seconds` != `second`.

Comment: Unrelated, but `interval` isn't a great name for the function: it's not an interval, it's something that *starts* an interval. It'll also start a *new* interval on every click, throwing away the reference to the previously-started interval. At best it's likely not what you want and will strand a bunch of running intervals.

Comment: Initial value of second is 59

Comment: See the second comment by Dave. That is the cause of your problem. You are subtracting 1 from `undefined`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make sure your state variable is set to greater than 0 and you should stop your interval when state value is 0, or just remove `parseInt` from `setState` so that it will not create any issue.

And one more thing you didn't use `this.state.seconds` inside `setState`
because the variable you mentioned inside `parseInt` method which is not valid without `this.state`

```
this.state = { second: 0 }

interval = () => { this.myInterval = setInterval(() => { this.setState({second: this.state.seconds - 1}) }, 1000)}
```

Comment: This duplicates the original issue (`seconds` != `second`) and introduces another potential bug in that `this.state.seconds` may not have the most recent value.

Comment: I rejected your question edit; it edited to reflect part of an answer, but it's also incorrect--the OP is correctly using state destructuring in a circumstance where you *must* take the current state as part of the state update function. Your answer, as noted in my first comment, uses potentially stale state and ignores the underlying problem.

Comment: I've also edit your answer to remove text-speak. There's a lot wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, you are decrementing from `seconds` (which doesn't exists that's where the `NaN`comes from) and setting the value to `second`.